# Using Javascript Range to move the cursor of an input Text using Keyboard right/left

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, cursor, range

I have a requirement to move the cursor character by character of an input text using keyboard right/left option. I am using angular 5 with IE 11 browser.  Below is my code. Can anyone please let me know if it is the right approach ?

```
var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if(key === 37 || key === 39){        
            event.stopPropagation();     
            let inputDocument = document.getElementById('numericinput');   
            let range = document.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);                       
            let iCaretPos = 0;
            if(key === 39 && this.iCaretPos < inputDocument.innerHTML.length){
                 console.log("inside if");
                 this.iCaretPos = this.iCaretPos +1;
                 range.setEnd(input.firstChild, 0);      
                 range.setStart(input.firstChild, this.iCaretPos);   
            }else if(key === 37 && iCaretPos > 0){
                 console.log("inside else");
                 this.iCaretPos = this.iCaretPos -1;
                 range.setEnd(input.firstChild, 0);      
                 range.setStart(input.firstChild, this.iCaretPos);  
            }  
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges;      
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, doesn't the browser itself provide the functionaltiy to move the cursor inside an input text box?

Comment: It is providing option using mouse but not keyboard. keyboard options are blocked somehow. I am not sure how to achieve it. Can you please advise ?

Comment: I've just tested the following lines inside ie11 and moving the cursor using the cursor keys works perfectly. `<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="test">
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is working for me but I am getting error at the last line. window.getSelection().addRange(range);  It says Unspecified error and I am not sure what kind of error it is.